# Can I capture the output of another process that I started?

Tags: linux, perl, system

I'm currently using `> /dev/null &` to have Perl script A run Perl script B totally independently, and it works fine.  Script B runs without throwing back any output and stays alive when Script A ends, even when my terminal session ends.

Not saying I need it, but is there a way to recapture its output if I wanted to?

Thanks

Comment: Redirect to a file or named pipe instead of /dev/null? With the pipe be cautious, it will fill up and then block by default if not read from.

Comment: @tink Your answer scared me, does `> /dev/null` ever fill up?

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's the beauty of it. But what goes to /dev/null stays in /dev/null ;)

Comment: If you want to start a program in the background, look at the `nohup` command-line utility. It

Answer (score 1):

Your code framework may look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# I'm a.pl
#...
system "b.pl > ~/b.out &";
while (1)
{
    my $time = localtime;
    my ($fsize, $mtime) = (stat "/var/log/syslog")[7,9];
    print "syslog: size=$fsize, mtime=$mtime at $time\n";
    sleep 60;
}
```

while the b.pl may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# I'm b.pl
while (1)
{
    my $time = localtime;
    my $fsize_a = (stat "/var/log/auth.log")[7];
    my $fsize_s = (stat "/var/log/syslog")[7];
    print "fsize: syslog=$fsize_s auth.log=$fsize_a at $time\n";
    sleep 60;
}
```

- a.pl and b.pl do their job independently.
- b.pl is called by a.pl as a background job, which sends its output to b.out(won't mess up the screen of a.pl)
- You can read b.out from some other terminal, or after a.pl is finished(or when a.pl is put to background temporarily)

About terminating the two scripts:

- `ctrl-c` for a.pl

  `killall b.pl` for b.pl

Note:

- b.pl will never terminate even when you terminate your terminal (Assumed that your terminal is run as a desktop application), so you don't need the `nohup` command to help. (Perhaps only useful in console)

  If your b.pl may spit out error messages from time to time, then you still need to deal with its stderr. It's left as your homework.

Comment: I am using /dev/null as I have no intention of looking at the output, I just mean if I wanted to can I redirect it to something else, then put it back?  I don't have to do this, am just curious if I can,

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer - You don't have to ALWAYS redirect b.pl's stdout to b.out. You can make an option to turn it on, while using `> /dev/null` as default redirection. However, you have to decide how to redirect before you run a.pl. It's not trivial job to switch in midway. And you can not recover anything already sent to /dev/null.